# Calling a matrix Ai in the i-th iteration of a loop

Tags: matlab

Last beginner question of the day...Working in matlab. Suppose one has matrices A1,...,An. How can one call do something to the Ai-th matrix on the i-th iteration of a loop? Actually I would like to concatenate all the matrices except the Ai-th one, but I can probably figure that out.

Comment: `Last beginner question of the day` - I doubt it. Anyway, [`what have you tried`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: You should not doubt the word of someone you do not know. I have tried finding basic MATLAB tutorials, but haven't found anything comprehensive. I would be very grateful to a link to something like this.

Comment: I am not doubting your word. I just have some experience on StackOverflow :-) Did you read the article I have linked to in my previous comment?

Comment: I appreciate the message of that article, by the way. But I am in a situation where I need to teach myself this language to create a program *today* and am getting stuck on some of the syntax issues. I know how to find basic commands and learn for the most part, but this issue is strange to me. Do I create an array of matrices? I don't know how to even try this, since I don't know MATLAB structures well.

Comment: Would be very happy with a link to a comprehensive tutorial that answered my question.

Comment: I am afraid that StackOverflow doesn't work that way. Of course you might always hope that someone will send you teh codez. Oh and by the way if you appreciate the message in that article you might try to adhere to it.

Comment: Now you are simply contradicting yourself.

Comment: May I know why I am contradicting myself?

Comment: Please tell me what you have tried first, in your attempt to understand my meaning.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by concatenate ? Why would one go through a loop (btw, you should consider loops in Matlab as your last solution, they are evil, remember Matlab is a matrix oriented programming language) to do it ? A = [A Ai] ?

Comment: I want to iteratively consider a function on the set of all data generated by all of my matrices except the i-th matrix. Not sure how one could create n such data sets without a for loop, at least in an elegant way.

Comment: Do you have a way to know which would be i value ? for i=1:n if i ~= yourValue A = [A Ai]; end end

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Maybe what I am doing is clumsy, but for a given i value I concatenate the other matrices (with two other for loops, one up to i-1, and the other starting at i+1. i know, i know...)

After I concatenate I'm going to be playing around with polyfit on the data of my new matrix, and so on, getting n different results. It's rather hard to talk here!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to do the following:

Instead of creating matrices in the way I did above, I will create an array of matrices.

> for i=1:n
>
> A{i}= matrix with nrows:ncolumns;
>
> end

Then you call the matrix in the obvious way.